# How I can prove that the last digit of $1+6^n+2\times 3^n+7^n+4^n+3\times9^{n}+4\times8^n$ is $3$ or $9$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion, golden-ratio

I have checked the first $14$ digits of Golden ratio, and I have found some attractive properties.  I have defined the sequence as

$6^n+1^n+8^n+0^n+3^n+3^n+9^n+8^n+8^n+7^n+4^n+9^n+8^n+9^n$.

Some properties I have noted are the following:

1/-The number: $61803398874989$ is a prime number, and the sum of digits of that number is also a prime number.

2/ 
 $6^n+1^n+8^n+0^n+3^n+3^n+9^n+8^n+8^n+7^n+4^n+9^n+8^n+9^n$ is congruent $1$ or $3 \bmod 4$.   It is a prime number for $n=1,2,37,61,70,81$ for $n<100$; for $n=3$ the term is cubic, and it can be written as  $4913=17^3$.

3/The number $61^3+80^3+33^3+98^3+87^3+49^3+89^3$  is a prime number and it holds for $61^3+80^3+33^3+98^3+87^3+49^3-89^3$; for $n=57$ also it is a prime number.

4/The last digits of the sequence  ($6^n+1^n+8^n+0^n+3^n+3^n+9^n+8^n+8^n+7^n+4^n+9^n+8^n+9^n$) is $3$ or $9$ using mathematica up to $n=10^6$ or just [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+of+%5B6%5En%2B1%5En%2B8%5En%2B0%5En%2B3%5En%2B3%5En%2B9%5En%2B8%5En%2B8%5En%2B7%5En%2B4%5En%2B9%5En%2B8%5En%2B9%5En%5D%2C+n%3D1+to+100).

Now I'm interested in this sequence, which is not mentioned in OEIS; I want to prove that really the last digit of $1+6^n+2\times 3^n+7^n+4^n+3\times9^{n}+4\times8^n$  is $3$ or $9$ .

Comment: I don't know  why always downvote to all of my question until if it were important at a least the downovoter respect effort of others , I spent a huge of time for that that is not a random question, and I'm daily provide all efforts to add something

Comment: it would be nice if the downvoter at least explained why the downvote

Comment: Is numerology as written. Please explain why it should be of interest *mathematically*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last digit is $3$, $9$, $3$, and $3$ for $n=1, 2, 3, $ and $4$, respectively.

Now can you prove $a^{n+4}\equiv a^n\bmod 10$ for $n\ge1$?

Hint:  $2$ and $5$ divide $a^5-a$.

Comment: As near as I can tell, this proof does not account for the last-digit value of $3$ for the exponent $n=0$. (I.e., the general assertion that $a^{n+4}\equiv a^n$ mod $10$ for all $a$ really requires $n\ge1$, not $n\ge0$.)

Comment: @BarryCipra:  I didn't consider the case $n=0$, and a close look suggests that OP didn't either:  for one thing, at the beginning of the question body it is defined as $\cdots+\color{blue}0^n+\cdots$, and moreover the Wolfram Alpha link in OP goes from $n=1 $ to $100$

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the disappearance of $0^n$ in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Taken mod $2$ we have

$$1+6^n+2\cdot3^n+7^n+4^n+3\cdot9^n+4\cdot8^n\equiv1+0+0+1+0+1+0\equiv1$$

Taken mod $5$ we have

$$1+6^n+2\cdot3^n+7^n+4^n+3\cdot9^n+4\cdot8^n\equiv1+1^n+2(-2)^n+2^n+(-1)^n+3(-1)^n+4(-2)^n\\
\equiv2+2^n+(-2)^n-(-1)^n\\
\equiv3+(2^n-1)(1+(-1)^n)\\
\equiv
\begin{cases}
4&\text{if } n\equiv2\mod4\\
3&\text{if } n\not\equiv2\mod4
\end{cases}$$

Putting these together, the last digit can only be $3$ or $9$, with the latter case occuring when $n\equiv2$ mod $4$ (i.e., for $n=2,6,10,14,\ldots$).